# How to upload an image using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, image-uploading

I have recorded a script to upload an image. It shows File not found exception. Can anyone please help? I want to upload the same image 1000 times?

Its a chat application like whatsapp where I want to send an image. This scenario needs to be recorded.

Comment: Show your post request for upload file. Jmeter is not able to find the file that is required to upload. Put the image in bin folder(optional) and provide full file path including file name. Helpful link:-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-test-image-upload-functionality-jmeter/        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405256/how-to-upload-image-through-jmeter

Comment: This is not helping me. Can you please help with another solution?

Comment: Please share error logs and test plan/ post request for reference. It will help to get quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the image into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation in order to be able to successfully record the image upload. [Browsers don't have access to the full path of the file due to security reasons](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly), they report only file name to JMeter therefore JMeter cannot locate the file hence you're getting the error.

So copy the image to JMeter's "bin" folder and you should be good to go. Make sure that the image exists in the bin folder during replay.

More information:

- [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)
- [`<input type="file">` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Value)